# Put device into offline status in adb

Tags: android, adb, offline

I have desktop application communicating with Android devices via adb. Sometimes device goes to offline state and my program does not work. Now I am trying to make workaround for it by disabling and enabling usb port programatically, but unfortunatelly I can not test it, because devices still remains in online state...

Is there any possibility to enforce offline state of device?

Comment: What do you mean by "online state" and "offline state"?

Comment: I mean the output state of adb devices command. It is connection state of the device.
Offline state occurs, when the instance is not connected to adb or is not responding.
See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html for more.

Comment: @Paweł          Did you ever find out how to put a device into a offline state?  I am trying to find out.

Thank you